# When did Kuradeel join Laughing Coffin?

Tags: sword-art-online

In *Episode 10 - Crimson Killing Intent* it is revealed that Kuradeel is a member of Laughing Coffin.

In *Episode 8 - The Sword Dance of Black and White* during Kuradeel's and Kirito's Duel there was a member of Laughing Coffin in the crowd watching the the fight.

I am wondering if Kuradeel joined Laughing Coffin before or after this Duel. if it was after was there any other reason for him to join aside from him wanting to get back at Kirito?

If it was before what purpose was there to have a member of Laughing Coffin inside the Knights of the Blood Oath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based off of the Chronological timeline, [Laughing Coffin](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Laughing_Coffin) recruited Kuradeel after his dual with Kirito. Aside from Kuradeel wishing to kill Kirito, no other reason for joining Laughing Coffin is mentioned.

> **October, 2024**
>
> Although the guild was vanquished during the crusade, PoH, who avoided the crusade, watched Kirito and Kuradeel's duel on the 74th Floor. After hearing that Kuradeel wished to kill Kirito, PoH approached Kuradeel some time prior to Kirito's mandatory training session with Kuradeel and Godfree. PoH then invited Kuradeel to his guild and taught him how to make paralysis poison.